# Addpath for Python like in Octave

Tags: python, function, path, octave

I am taking an introductory course in machine learning [[0](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/)], and it teaches Octave. The course introduces a function called addpath() that allows Octave to look in multiple directories for files [[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulating-the-Load-Path.html)].

Does an equivalent function exist in Python? If not, is there a way to implement an equivalent function in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `sys.path` which is a list of directories in which Python will look for modules.  It can be manipulated like any other list, e.g.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/my/special/directory")
```

Comment: I see that sys.path already has paths to get modules. Can I simply change the source code of the sys module on my system to default to having more directories of my choosing?

Comment: I'd instead recommend creating a `sitecustomize.py` for this and put it in some directory that's already in your path (perhaps `site-packages`). Python will execute it automatically at startup.